# Auth0 Social Login with HS256 JWT

Tags: jwt, auth0

i am wondering if it is possioble to create a social login and receive the JWT in HS256 ??

This is what i am using at the moment and i am only able to receive RS256 JWTs...

```
 this.webAuth.authorize({
   connection: 'google-oauth2'
 });
```

Cheers, have a great Day/Night!

Khadim

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use `RS256` or `HS256` is controlled at the Client level. You can use the Auth0 Dashboard to switch between the two. It is under `Clients -> (Your Client) -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Oauth`.

From your code snippet above, suggests you are using Auth0.js library. With Auth0.js version 8+, RS256 is the default and `parseHash` will fail if your Client is using HS256. See [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v8/migration-guide#the-parsehash-method) for details.

As detailed in the docs, you can choose to implement your own parseHash if you wish to use HS256 - an example of doing this is [here](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/blob/master/src/web-auth/index.js#L97).

Another option, although not particularly recommended, is to use an older version of auth0.js.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I already switched it in the Dashboard. This is already working for the Email-Password login but the Social logins still using RS256..

Comment: Why do you need HS256?

Comment: Would like to easily approve the token in Sails.JS :)